# adding searchBar to navigationBar in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchbar

i'm trying to add a searchBar to the navigationBar. i've researched a bit and this is what i've done so far:

The problem is nothing appear to the navigationBar using this code.

```
    searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44))
    searchBar?.delegate = self
    searchBar?.showsCancelButton = true


    searchController = UISearchDisplayController()
    searchController?.delegate = self
    searchController?.searchResultsDelegate = self

    searchController?.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = true
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code that worked for me:

```
 lazy   var searchBars:UISearchBar = UISearchBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 20))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var leftNavBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBars)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftNavBarButton
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
lazy var searchBar = UISearchBar(frame: .zero)
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 navigationItem.titleView = searchBar}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this

```
private let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {

 self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
 self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
}
```